# How to load a .osm file as a basemap tiles in openlayers 3?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, xml

I am working on an app that needs to be used offline so I have downloaded a map in an .osm file, I need to load it as a basemap. I did some research and found this code I used but it shows the map as a vector layer:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.OSMXML(),
                url: 'Maps/Tangier_Medina.osm',
                projection: 'EPSG:4326'
            })
})
```

I thought at first that specifying the format

```
ol.format.OSMXML()
```

will be enough but I need it to be a basemap with tiles.

Anyone knows how please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a basemap with tiles, you need to render them yourself with Mapnik, Maperitive, TileMill or else. Depending on the extent of your area, you will get billions of tiles, mostly filled with ocean water.

This is definitely not a task for Openlayers javascript.

The OSMXML function might be useful to overlay some POI from the Openstreetmap database, but not much more.

Comment: I used the OSMXML format before in java for an android app and thought it may work for javascript too. Thanks for the answer I'm going on with TileMill

Comment: There is an example at http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-osm.html, but you have to apply the styling yourself. And it might be terribly slow on larger areas.